# What does it mean for a grammar to be LR(0)?

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata, formal-grammars, compilers

I am unsure what it means for a grammar to be $X$. More specifically, what it means for a grammar to be LR(0).

For part of an assignment I had to form the DFA for a grammar, which I had no issues with. And then I have been asked whether the grammar is LR(0).
My guess is yes, but not because I understand *exactly* what it means. I would assume it isn't if, when creating the DFA I came across some strange behaviors that prevented the DFA making any sense (if you know what I mean/if *I'm* making any sense).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A bottom-up parsing technique, used for parsing most context-free grammars is `LR(k)`: `L` indicates that the input is parsed from left to right, `R` indicates that in the parsing process a rightmost derivation is produced; the number `k` indicates how many lookahead symbols are used.

An LR parsing scheme consists of: input, output, stack, a parsing program and a parsing table divided into two parts (actions (shift, reduce) and goto).

The idea is that the parsing program reads characters from an input buffer one at a time and uses the stack to store strings of the form s<sub>0</sub>X<sub>1</sub>s<sub>1</sub>X<sub>2</sub>s<sub>2</sub>...s<sub>m</sub>X<sub>m</sub> where s<sub>0</sub> is the initial state, the only one present at the beginning of the computation on the stack, while s<sub>m</sub> is the state at the top of the stack. Each X<sub>i</sub> is a grammatical symbol while each s<sub>i</sub> is a symbol that identifies a state. Each state describes the information contained in the stack before it; the combination of the state at the top of the stack and the current input symbol is used to index the parsing table and to determine the parser's shift-reduce decisions.

Given a grammar, to prove that this is `LR(0)` builds the DFA of viable prefixes.
The first prefix is always `S' -> .S` because we consider the grammar increased. Then follow the rules to build the LR(0) parsing table.

A grammar is LR(0) if each position in the parsing table LR(0) contains at most one element.

Furthermore, the LR(0) languages all enjoy the `prefix property`. So if a language does not have this property, we can immediately say that it is not LR(0).

If the grammar is ambiguous then it cannot be LR(k) for any k.

Comment: Ah, it all makes sense. It's more information than I needed, but I am grateful nonetheless.

Comment: I tried to give the best possible answer given my knowledge :)